# Android Portrait vs Landscape

Tags: android, user-interface, landscape-portrait

I know that it is possible to have a layout for both portrait and landscape mode (that's not the problem). Say in portrait mode I want to display 3 textviews (actually I have 3 distinct graphs, one for each axis xyz) and in landscape I only want one textview (in my case one graph that contains all 3 axis), all of there view got their own id.

Now in the corresponding activity, how do you setup the ui controls? Because in landscape mode there's only one textview whereas in portrait mode I got 3. So when I'm in portrait mode I'm only able to write something in textview 1 2 and 3 but nothing into landscape's textview and vice versa.

Manually checking if the ui control is here (not null) can't be the right solution, right?

e.g

Say in portrait mode I have a textview with id 'text1' and in landscape one with 'text2'.
Now in the activity's on create method I do the following:

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

text1.setText("some text");
text2.setText("some other text");
```

I'll always get a `NullPointerException` because in either case one of the textviews does not exist. It would be possible to check if the field is not null before using it, but that would introduce more logic to take care of - so it gets less maintainable

Answer (score 1):

You can create in both layouts and hide them with visibility="gone" to keep a valid reference to the view

Answer (score 1):

Because you may not want to waste resources setting and processing fields that are not visible in your layout, unless this makes sense in your app, you should check for `null` Views and this would give you and idea of which orientation you are processing:

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

if ( text1 != null ) text1.setText("some text");
if ( text2 != null ) text2.setText("some other text");
```

Comment: actually this is what I'm doing right now, but I'm using the textviews in more than one place, and always putting the not null check in front of kind of blows up the code a bit and makes it less readable - so I thought there might be another best practice. 

Of course the problem with setting the views invisible 'wastes' ressources but in my case that's not really an issue so I chose to go for it since I don't need any extra logic in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by make some textviews visible/invisible depending on which mode you're using?
You could detect which mode you're using by : getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

I don't know if that really answer to your question but..

Best,